# Before-and-After plugin compatible with iPad

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad

I'd like to use a Before-and-After jQuery plugin on my site, but I haven't been able to find any that are compatible with iPads, so that you can drug the before-and-after divider with a finger on in iPad/iPhone and with a mouse on a desktops/laptops.

Comment: Which ones have you tried that don't work on either the iPad or mouse?

Comment: Catchmyfame's is if you add the touch/punch plugin.